# Solving Linear Least Squares with Linear Inequality Constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares

Given:

$$
\begin{aligned}
A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \\
y \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1} \\
c, d \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1} \\
d \geq c \geq 0 \\
y \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$

I seek $\hat{x}$:

$$ \hat{x} = \arg\min_{x} \|Ax - y\|_2 \\
s.t. \; \hat{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1} , \; d \geq A \hat{x} \geq c$$

How do I compute $\hat{x}$?

Comment: I wrote a MATLAB Code which solves this problem in the formulation I wrote below. Would you like me to share it?

Comment: Thanks, but the question is no longer relevant to me. Feel free to share it if you think it benefits others who come across this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Royi's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1403593/118872) shows how to solve it with `lsqlin`.

You could also use [alglib](http://www.alglib.net/optimization/boundandlinearlyconstrained.php) under the GPL license, using a form of an active-set algorithm.

Active set resources:

- http//www.alglib.net/optimization/boundandlinearlyconstrained.php#header1
- http//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_set
- http//research.harkegard.se/papers/cdc2002_ca.pdf

Comment: Hi, I don't see how can you use MATLAB for the 2 inequalities he mentioned.

Comment: @Drazick I think I misread $lb \le x \le ub$ as $lb \le A \cdot x \le ub$ in the [lsqlin documentation](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html), but it appears you cleverly made it work anyway.

Comment: Hi, If it does, I think you should switch the marked answer.

Comment: I wonder, is there a way to make Least Squares with Inequality Constraints fit ADMM or OLS framwework?

Comment: @Royi Updated it to get as close as possible to ordinary least squares

Comment: As far as I could see it, you created a new LS problem with new auxiliary variable, equality constraint and inequality constrain on the auxiliary variable. If you could solve it using regular LS I'd see the point. Yet since you're using Built In solve I'd think the other structure I suggested is equivalent. Do you see any advantage to yours?

Comment: Moreover, it seems your answer only deals with the constraints of the original question. It doesn't take into consideration the objective function. It should be $ \arg \min_{x} {\left\| A x - y \right\|}^{2} \; \text{s. t.} \; B \bar{x} = e, \; D \bar x \geq 0 $ Where $ D $ extract $ z $ from $ \bar{x} $.

Comment: @Royi Ah I see, I forgot I requested argmin back then. In that case, least squares is indeed not appropriate. I've reverted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

By defining the problem as following:

$$
\begin{aligned}
A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \\
y \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1} \\
c, d \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1} \\
d \geq c \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$

We're after:

$$ \hat{x} = \arg\min_{x} \|Ax - y\|_2 \\
s.t. \; \hat{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1} , \; A \hat{x} \geq c , \; A \hat{x} \leq d $$

Since $ c $ is positive, we can also write the following:

$$ A x \geq c \Leftrightarrow -A x \leq -c $$

Now, by defining $ \tilde{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
-A \\ 
A
\end{bmatrix} $ we can rewrite:

$$ Ax \geq c, Ax \leq d \Leftrightarrow \tilde{A} x = \begin{bmatrix}
-A \\ 
A
\end{bmatrix} x \leq e = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-c \\ 
d
\end{bmatrix} $$

Namely the problem has become:

$$ \hat{x} = \arg\min_{x} \|Ax - y\|_2 \\
s.t. \; \tilde{A} \hat{x} \leq e $$

Which is now in the regular form of [Quadratic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) and can be solved using [`lsqlin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html).

Comment: Updated original question to match your (I believe) equivalent problem definition since it's more elegant

Comment: How does this compare to using an active-set algorithm?

Comment: Could you refer me to active set algorithm?

Comment: I believe I used [this](http://www.alglib.net/optimization/boundandlinearlyconstrained.php#header1) as active set algorithm