# Linear Least Square Optimization with Linear Equality Constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

What is the exact solution $x_{n \times 1}$ of the following constrained optimization problem
\begin{align*}
&\min \|A x - b\|^2 \\
s.t.& C x = 0
\end{align*}
where $A$ is full column rank $m \times n$ matrix ($m>n$); $b$ is $m \times 1$ matrix; $C$ is full row rank $1 \times n$ matrix?

Answer (score 1):

The Lagragian is the following:

$$
L = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{m}(\sum \limits_{j = 1}^{2}a_{ij}x_{j} - b_{i})^{2} + \lambda \sum \limits_{j = 1}^{n}c_{i}x_{i}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_{k}} = 2 \sum \limits_{j = 1}^{n}(\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n}a_{ij}a_{ik})x_{j} - 2 n \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{m}b_{i} a_{ik} + \lambda c_{k} = 0
$$

There are $n + 1$ equations and $n + 1$ unknowns.

Comment: Just to make it clear: $n$ equations come from $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_k}$, the last is the constraint $Cx=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is given by:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{3}
\arg \min_{x} & \quad & \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} & \quad & C x = \boldsymbol{0}
\end{alignat*}
$$

The Lagrangian is given by:

$$ L \left( x, \nu \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} + {\nu}^{T} C x $$

From KKT Conditions the optimal values of $ \hat{x}, \hat{\nu} $ obeys:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
{A}^{T} A & {C}^{T} \\ 
C & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{x} \\ 
\hat{\nu}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
{A}^{T} b \\ 
\boldsymbol{0}
\end{bmatrix} $$

Now all needed is to solve the above with any Linear System Solver.

Comment: What happens in the case that the constraints are of the form:  Cx <= 0 ?? How it affects the solution proposed here?

Comment: @noob-mathematician, Please open a question and link here. I will try to solve it.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73712, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625850.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915740/linear-least-squares-and-lagrange

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$Since the constraint is linear it has an explicit solution in terms of the nullspace projector
$$\eqalign{
P &= I-C^+C \qiq P^T=P=P^2 \\
}$$
$$\eqalign{
Cx &= 0 \qiq x = Pu
}$$
where a new unconstrained vector variable $u$ has been introduced.

In terms of $u,\,$ the objective function is likewise **unconstrained**
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \|APu-b\|^2 \\
}$$
Thus it can be immediately solved using a pseudoinverse
$$\eqalign{
u &= \LR{AP}^+b \qiq
x = P\LR{AP}^+b = \LR{I-C^+C}\LR{A-AC^+C}^+b \\
}$$
${\bf NB\!:}\;$ This solution remains valid when $C$ is an arbitrary matrix, not simply a vector.