# linear least squares and lagrange

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I want to solve the standard problem  $\min_{x\in D} \frac{1}{2}||Ax-b ||$ where:

D = \begin{matrix} 0\leq x_1 \leq C
\\ |x_2| \leq x_1 \hspace{2mm} \text{and} \hspace{2mm} |x_2| \leq C- x_1
\\ 0\leq x_3\leq D
\end{matrix}

where $C,D>0$. I want to find a solution numerically.

So the idea is the following:

1) Solve the unconstrained problem in which there exist a closed form solution. If the solution is in the domain $D$ stop. Else: 
2) Seek for a solution in the boundary using Lagrange multipliers.

Does anyone know how may I solve the problem with Lagrange-multipliers on the boundary (especially in the second inequalities)?

There is a scipy-python optimizer but the bounds of the x-vector that can be used as inputs do not depend on the x-vector components...Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should be easy to formulate and solve using CVX, CVXPY, or similar convex optimization tool. Note: don't include $0 \le |x_3|$, which those tools won't accept (due to non-convexity), but which iis an automatically satisfied and unnecessary constraint. Using such a tool, you don't need to concern yourself with Lagrange multipliers, because the tool submits an appropriate numerical optimization problem to a solver, and then transforms the results from the solver back to your originally entered problem.

Comment: Is x 3 by 1, i.e., is column vector of scalars $x_1, x_2, x_3$?  Then 2nd row of constraints is $-x_2 \le x_1, x_2 \le x_1, x_2 \le C-x_1, -x_2 \le C-x_1$.  That is just a linearly-constrained linear least squares problem, for which there is off-the-shelf software; for instance, MATLAB's https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html .

Comment: The idea is that this problem seems easy to solve by using Lagrange-multipliers (the author suggests on http://www.zeliade.com/whitepapers/zwp-0005.pdf, page 6) and at the same time faster than any other fancy optimiser. I am looking for a Lagrange-like approach here.

Comment: If that paper has a great algorithm (I have no idea whether it does), feel free to use it.  I am providing you options to use well-established reliable software, which is likely to be more reliable than your home-brew (programming) approach. Do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am working in Python and the only available least square optimizer is https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html . The bounds in the optimizer are fixed numbers. I think even in Matlab the same problem appears. The UB and LB have to be fixed numbers

Comment: This problem should be trivial to input and run in CVXPY. http://www.cvxpy.org/ (CVXPY including solver at no charge) . But that will never be the speed king. MATLAB's lsqlin (in Optimization toolbox) can handle this.  I mentioned those in an earlier comment because they can handle general linear constraints.