# Linear Least Squares Problem with Inequality Constraints on Residual

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares, numerical-optimization

I have an over-determined linear least-squares problem
$$\min_{\vec{x}}\Vert\mathbf{A}\vec{x}-\vec{b}\Vert_2^2,$$
where $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $\vec{b}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $n>m$.

I can solve that with standard least-square techniques and get an optimal solution $\vec{x}^{*}$. However, I have a specific requirement on the residual vector $\vec{r}\in\mathbb{R}^m$, i.e.,
$$
\vec{r}=\mathbf{A}\vec{x}^{*}-\vec{b}.
$$
I want every component of the residual vector $r_i$ to have the following constraints:
$$
\vert r_i\vert <\frac{1}{2}, \text{ with } 1\leq i \leq m.
$$

How can I find a solution for $\vec{x}$ that adheres to those constraints?

The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ has three entries per row. The number of rows/equations is in the $10^6$ and the number of columns/unknowns is something like $10^4$ to $10^5$.

Comment: You may consider using an interior point method. The matrix you must solve at each iteration can be factorized efficiently with sparse-direct methods, because $A$ has only 3 nonzero entries per row.

Comment: @NickAlger The rows of $\mathbf{A}$ also sum to 1. But for my least square problem, I tried a sparse-solver from Eigen and that took forever. Solving the normal equation was much fast and stable (even though I squared the condition number, but it seems peaceful).

Answer (score 2):

In general, the condition that every $|r_i| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ can be written as
$$
\|\vec{r}\|_\infty \leq \frac{1}{2}
$$

So your optimization problem becomes
$$
\min_{\vec{r}} \quad \|\mathbf{A} \vec{x} - \vec{b}\|_2
\text{    subject to    } \| A \vec{x} - \vec{b} \|_\infty \leq \frac{1}{2}
$$

Any standard convex solver can solve such problems, e.g. [CVX](http://cvxr.com/) or [YALMIP](https://yalmip.github.io/).

## Update

If your generic convex solver cannot efficiently handle the sparsity structure and solves the problem slowly, there are several alternatives. Here are some of them.

### Conditional Gradient (Frank Wolfe)

Solves problems of the form $\min_{x \in C} f(x)$, where $C$ is a compact set and $f$ is continuously differentiable, and has a Lipschitz continuous gradient. In your case, you can define $C = \{ x : \|A x - b\|_\infty \leq 0.5 \}$ and $f = \|A x - b\|_2^2$.

The algorithm follows the following iterative steps:

1. Direction Finding - find $s_k$ which minimizes $s_k^T \nabla f(x_k)$ subject to $s_k \in C$. In our case, it reduces to a linear program. Although it is quite large, solvers like Gurobi can handle it quite quickly.
2. Set $t = \frac{2}{k+2}$ and $x_{k+1} = x_k + t(s_k - x_k)$.

Alternatively, in step (2) you can perform a line-search and find $t \in [0, 1]$ which minimizes $f(x_k + t(s_k - x_k)$. This is a simple minimization problem of minimizing a parabola over an interval.

### Solve a Dual

Your problem can be, by substituting auxiliary variables $r = A x - b$, written as:
$$
\min_{x, r} \quad \|A x - b\|_2^2 \text{ s.t. } r = A x - b, \|r\|_\infty \leq 0.5
$$
A Lagrangian with multipliers for the equality constraints is
$$
L(x, r; \lambda) = \|A x - b\|_2^2 + \lambda^T(A x - b - r)
$$
A dual can be obtained by
$$
q(\lambda) = \min_{x, r} L(x, r; \lambda) = 
\min_x \{ \| A x - b\|_2^2 + (A^T \lambda)^T x \} + \min_r \{ -\lambda^T r :\|r\|_\infty \leq 0.5 \} - \lambda^T b
$$
The first minimum is as easy as least-squares - just compare its gradient to zero. You obtain
$$
A^T (A x - b) + A^T \lambda = 0
$$
Assuming your $A^T A$ is invertible, you obtain an explicit formula for $x^*$ as a function of $\lambda$, and an explicit formula for the first minimum. I will leave it to you, but it is a quadratic function of $\lambda$, which I denote as $q_0(\lambda)$.
The second minimum is, by Cauchy-Schwartz, $-\|\lambda\|_1$. Hence, your dual problem is maximizing $q_0(\lambda) -\|\lambda\|_1- \lambda^T b$, or written as minimum, it is 
$$
\min_{\lambda} -q_0(\lambda) + \|\lambda\|_1 + \lambda^T b
$$
Since $q_0$ is a concave quadratic function of $\lambda$, it becomes a simple Lasso problem. There is a vast variety of algorithms to solve it, including, for example, [FISTA](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/080716542). Having solved it and found the optimal $\lambda^*$, you can use the formula of $x^*$ as a function of $\lambda^*$ we derived to obtain your optimal $x^*$.

### Fast Dual Proximal Gradient

[FDPG](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167637713001454) is a direct first order method for solving convex problems of the form $f(x) + g(A x)$, where $g$ is a convex extended real-valued function (can have $+\infty$ as its value). In your case, we set $f(x) = \|A x - b\|_2^2$ and 
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
  0 & \|x - b\|_\infty \leq 0.5 \\
  +\infty & 
\end{cases}
$$
The algorithm requires knowledge of the strong-convexity parameter of $f$, which in your case the minimum eigenvalue of $A^T A$. And also requires being able to compute the proximal mapping of $g$, which in your case is the projection onto the ball $\{ x : \|x - b\|_\infty \leq 0.5 \}$ which is quite easily done. In each iteration, you will have to solve a system of linear equations whose associated matrix is $A^T A$. You can Cholesky-Factor it once before running the algorithm, to make each iteration efficient.

Have fun solving!

Comment: With $10^6$ entries in $r$ and $10^4$ to $10^5$ columns in $A$, this problem is large enough that solving it as a linearly constrainted convex QP using CVX or YALMIP might not be practical.  A first-order method might be more practical.

Comment: @Brian-Borchers How would a first-order method work for that problem?

Comment: @Alex-Shtof You think Gurobi can handle problems like that?

Comment: I believe it can, since your matrix $A$ is very sparse.

Comment: A lot depends on how sparse $AA^{T}$ and how sparse its factors are.  If $AA^{T}$ is diagonal then the problem is separable and trivial to solve.  If $AA^{T}$ is not very sparse then you may not have enough memory to store it or its factors.  It's certainly worth a try simply because it's so easy to test.

Comment: @Alex-Shtof: From a brief look at Gurobi documentation, I am not sure whether Gurobi can deal with the infinity norm on the constraints

Comment: It's very easy to rewrite the infinity norm constraint as a bunch of linear constraints.  You want to minimize $\| Ax - b \|_{2}^{2}$ subject to $Ax-r=b$, and subject to bounds constraints on the residuals, $r_{i} \leq 1/2$, $r_{i} \geq -1/2$, for $i=1, 2, \ldots, m$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers So effectively it boils down to this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625850/solving-linear-least-squares-with-linear-inequality-constraints i only found that yesterday night after revisiting my question.

Comment: Please let us know whether using a linear constrained QP solver actually works out for your problem.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: Using Gurobi, I am, in fact able, to directly specify the problem using a quadratic program. I could also specify the constraints as stated in my question directly. Gurobi runs, however, out of memory if the problem is too big. I managed with 2359296 knows and 33528 unknowns and got solutions in the order of minutes.

Comment: @AlexShtof: I might use FPGA soon to speed up my Gurobi result.